# Multiple ng-app inside one root-app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularjs.Using multiple ng-apps in same page. like app2 inside app1 and app1 inside rootApp.

`controller1` has one `$http` service it will retrieve the id and name and assign it to `$rootScope`.

I want to use that values in `controller2` in app2.

But the problem is both app1 called first and then app2 called immediately without getting id and name.

Because service takes some time to retrieve the id and name value.

I want to call app2 after getting the id and name from app1.  How i can achieve this,

```
<body ng-app="rootApp">
...
<div ng-app="app1" ng-controller ="controller1">


.....

<div ng-app="app2" ng-controller="controller2">

</div>

</div>

</body>

var app1 = angular.module('app1', []); /

app1.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $filter, $rootScope) {

$http.get().success(function(data){
$rootScope.id=data.id;
$rooTScope.name=data.name;
});
});

var app2 = angular.module('app2', []); /

app2.controller('controller2', function ($scope, $filter, $rootScope) {

//here i want to use that $rootscopeValues of id and name

});
```

Comment: Not possible. 1.x => 1 HTML Page ==>> 1 ng-app. Better use Angular2 where you can manage multiple mini app requirements better. Unless you dont want to use it and want to use components or multiple ng-controllers instead of 2 ng-app in 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one ng-app and multiple ng-controllers. Pay attention how you spell $rootScope.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller1', function($scope, $filter, $rootscope){
   $http.get().success(function(data){
     $rootScope.id = data.id;
     $rootScope.name = data.name;
   });

})
.controller('controller2', function($scope, $filter, $rootscope){
   console.log($rootScope.id);
   console.log($rootScope.name);
});
```

The document body:

```
<body ng-app="app">
...
<div  ng-controller ="controller1">


.....

<div ng-controller="controller2">

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: if you have the app1 and app2, you can define angular.module('app', [ 'app1', 'app2') and all controllers will be visible

Comment: Only one ng-app is binded per HTML document, and angular will initialise one only. 
There are cases where you would need two apps, but I think the person asking this question is just starting to learn angular so he applied the concept of the controller to the app as well.

Comment: I igree with you. And also, I prefer to use angular.bootstrap(...) to eliminate conditions of duplicate (or miss) of the ng-app.